# Найти товар с последнего документа. Laravel mysql

Tags: mysql, база-данных, laravel, запрос

Допустим прием товара осуществляется по 2 таблицам **documents, products**
document = id, title, data
products = id_product, id_document, quantity, price

Нужно найти последний документ(document) который содержит в себе определенный id_product. А также вывести все их данные **(->select('documents.*', 'products.*'))**

Чёт вообще не могу понять куда копать.
Нашел поиск по наивысшей дате, но как указать, что в этом документе должен быть указан данный товар.

```
\DB::table('documents')
            ->max('data');
```

Как это объединить с max? думаю вообще не туда копаю

```
\DB::table('documents as doc')
            ->join('products as prod', 'doc.id','=','prod.id_document')
            ->where('prod.id_product', '=', 5)
            ->get();
```

Прошу помочь решить, такую не большую задачку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно лучше.. всё это делается через отношения

```
class Document extends Model
{
    ...

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class, 'document_id', 'id');
    }

}
```

Потом в коде используете

```
$productId = 10;

$document = Document::whereHas('products', function($query) use ($productId) {
    $query->where('id', productId);
})->orderBy('data', 'desc')->first();

foreach($document->products as $product) {
    dump($product);
}
```

И переименуйте data в date, если речь о дате.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую.

Comment: Дайте обратную связь, получилось или нет...

Comment: Да, я пробывал, так тоже все работает.

Answer (score 0):

Наверно нашел решение. Вроде работает, но чёт думаю можно лучше сделать.

```
\DB::table('products as prod')
            ->select('prod.*','document .*')
            ->leftJoin('document AS doc', 'prod.id_document' ,'=', 'main.id')
            ->where('prod.id_product', '=', 1)
            ->orderBy('doc.data', 'DESC')
            ->first();
```